# Key compare using dictionary

Tags: python, file, list, dictionary, compare

I have a file with the following structure:

system.action.webMessage=An error has happened during web access.
system.action.okMessage=Everything is ok.
core.alert.inform=Error number 5512.

I need a script to compare the keys in 2 files with this structure. I was working in a script to convert the file into a dictionary and use the dictionary structure to compare de keys (strings before '=') in both files and tells me with value from which key is equal.

```
file = open('system.keys','r')
lines = []
for i in file:
    lines.append(i.split('='))

dic = {}
for k, v in lines:
    dic[k] = v
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Any one have some clue or help? :(
I've try lots of things that I found in google but no solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file = open('system.keys','r')
lines = []
for i in file:
    lines.append(i.partition('='))

dic = {}
for k,_,v in lines:
    dic[k] = v
```

or using split

```
myfile = open('system.keys','r')
dic = dict(i.split("=",1) for i in myfile)
```

since `dict()` knows how to make a dictionary from a sequence of `(key,value)` pairs

Answer (score 0):

If a line has more than one '=' in it, you'll get a list with more than two items, while your for-loop (`for k, v in items`) expects that each list will only have two items.

Try using `i.split('=', 1)`.

For example:

```
>>> "a=b=c".split('=')
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> "a=b=c".split('=', 1)
['a', 'b=c']
```

Comment: I got this error only in the secound 'for', when it trys to convert the list into a dictionary.
Both files has only one '=' in each line.

Comment: @Leonardo, that is because `lines` has items with more than 2 elements in it